# creating a mock JWT token for testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jwt, nodejs-express-server

I'm trying to create a test that will test the following branch.

```js
if (req.body.sessionToken) {
  let sessionToken = req.body.sessionToken;
  let tokenData = jwt.verify(sessionToken,config.secretSessionKey);
  sessionID = tokenData.sessionID;
}
```

I tried creating a mock JSON response containing a sessionToken key with a random value that will be sent but I'm getting a **UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed error.** I believe that I only have to provide the mock sessionToken in the right format to run the test since based on the test coverage, I'm getting the error on the

> let sessionTokenData = jwt.verify(sessionToken,config.secretSessionKey);

but I have to idea how should it be written.

Here is a part of my test. I'm calling the /authenticate endpoint then sending the sessionToken JSON that will contain the mock sessionToken value.

```
 return request
  .post("/authenticate")
  .send(sessionToken)
  .then(response => {
    let body = JSON.parse(response.text); })
```

Comment: What does your test look like?

Comment: edited the question and added a part of my test

Comment: You can mock `jwt.verify` method altogether, since it is a library method and was tested already

Comment: how can I mock it all at once? and will it still cover the branch since it needs the req.body.sessionToken?

Comment: `I tried creating a mock JSON response containing a sessionToken key` - how are you creating the JWT which is in the `sessionToken` field?

Comment: here is the mock req I created:    "sessionToken": {
        "userEmail": "test@gmail.com",
        "userPassword": "12345678",
        "sessionId": "95ce5656-605d-42d5-9119-a82ef312325d", "sessionToken":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjdkRC1nZWNOZ1gxWmY3R0xrT3ZwT0IyZGNWQSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2NvbnRvc28uY29tIiwiaXNzIjoia"
    }

Comment: did you just show a shortened token in the comment or is your session token exactly like this in your code? If you used exactly this token, then the *jwt malformed error* should be no surprise, because it is malformed

Comment: it is a shortened one since there is a char limit in the comments but I'm using a working token as a mock